# Modular Quiz in Swift

Tags: architecture, swift-language

I've been working on the architecture of my Apps for a while.

In the past I've used a SQLite database which I opened in the AppDelegate (Oh dear), and then created a global variable (really!) to store the questions.

I'm going to re-write this.

My thinking around the structure of this is to create separate modules for processing the SQLite database, creating a model of all the questions that will then be accessed by a Quiz manager. The Quiz manager should be able to request questions from the local SQLite database, and/or (in the future) an API call.

The way I'm thinking of structuring this is as follows:

[image]

The main question is where the database itself should go? The file I think should be in the App bundle, and passed to the Quiz manager and then on to the SQLite manager ... I think?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The individual who knows what the connection details are, is the application itself, or the configuration file that it somehow loads.

However `QuizManager` should not care about the `SQLiteManager`. It should not even know about `SQLiteManager`. It should only care about receiving an object that somehow lets it perform some question related actions like retrieving or saving.

In your case (in pseudo code):

```
interface Question
{
   ...
}

interface Questions
{
    int size();
    Question operator[](int index);
}

interface Repository
{
   //returns a random selection of up to total questions.
   Questions SelectRandomQuestions(int total);

   //returns a Question object that represents the question in the database.
   Question AddQuestion(Question newQuestion);

   //whatever other operations.
   ...
}
```

Now `SQLiteManager` implements that `Repository` interface. In fact go wild, you can provide other implementations like: a memory structure, or a MySQL connection.

At the start of your program create a copy of the `Repository` implementation passing in any details that the implementation needs to initialise itself. Now pass that implementation to whomever needs a `Repository`.

```
class SQLiteManager : Repository
{
   ...
}

main()
{
    var config = getConfigSomehow();

    var repository = new SQLiteManager(config.sqliteconfig);
    var quizManager = new QuizManager(repository);

    ...
}
```

Simple IoC, and Dependency Injection. The rest of your code base no longer cares about a file, or about SQLite, it only cares about questions and an object that will retrieve/persist them. Later on you can completely change that implementation and nothing else will break or need to be rewritten.

```
class APIRepository : Repository
{
   ...
}

main()
{
    var config = getConfigSomehow();

    var repository = new APIRepository(config.apidetails);
    var quizManager = new QuizManager(repository);

    ...
}
```

Comment: If the repository instantiates the QuizManager, we'd tightly couple the QuizManager to the APIRepository. However, the QuizManager should be able to (eventually) use a mixture of API calls / local storage to deliver properly formed questions to the App.  I'm not quite clear on how I might do that...

Comment: The repository does not instantiate the QuizManager, the Application does. The QuizManager is just accepting an object that implements the repository interface. The Application is responsible for constructing an appropriate repository, and then passing that to the QuizManager constructor as a Repository not any given implementation. To that end you could implement a repository that attempts a local lookup through the SQLite db and if that is insufficient, calls to the API and caches the results in the SQLite db.